# How to take screenshot of very large Database Diagram in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, screenshot, ssms, diagram

I have created a diagram in SSMS for my database. There are approximately 120 tables are used in this diagram. the problem is that when I copy that diagram from the `Edit->Copy Diagram to Clipboard` and paste it to `MSPaint` it gives me error. `Error getting the Clipboard data!`. I have also tried **Fast Stone Capture** utility to capture scrolled window. But, it is not taking screenshot properly. So, How do I take screenshot of very large Database Diagram?

Comment: Have you tried pasting the clipboard to another program? Like MS Word, Gimp, Paint.NET etc.

Comment: Also try with beloe link. Convert XPS to PDF/Image by using online converter.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34132/how-export-a-sql-server-2008-diagram-to-pdf-filetype

Comment: I have tried in MS Word. But, it gets resized automatically to fit to the document. @mnme

Comment: @Nimesh Try right-clicking on the image in Word and use the "Save as picture" option as described [here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/save-a-picture-as-a-jpg-gif-or-png-HA010354818.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To minimize resizing in Microsoft word go to "page layout" and choose "size/more pagesizes" and set width and height to max(55,87 cm * 55,87 cm)